# Como instalar SharpDX.XImput en otro equipo

Tags: c#

Acabo terminar un programa el cual usa `SharpDX.XImput` y para compartirlo he copiado directamente la carpeta `debug` que te crea `Visual Studio` al compilar el programa.

En mi equipo el programa se ejecuta sin ningún tipo de problema pero cuando intento ejecutarlo en otro este se bloquea y deja de funcionar nada más iniciarse sin dejar mensajes de error o de excepciones.

He estado testeando cual podría ser el problema y comentando líneas de código me he dado cuenta que el problema es todo el código que usa la librería `SharpDX.XImput`, por ello me gustaría saber como instalarlo o si solo con los .dll que deja en la carpeta debug debería de funcionar.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he optado por cambiar de librería a `SlimDX` para capturar el mando y ya si me funciona en otros equipos.

Prácticamente es igual a `SharpDX` para lo que necesito y además encontré un tutorial muy bien explicado y sencillo de usarla para capturar el mando de Xbox, que es el uso que le quería dar. Dejo [aquí el link](http://hdeleon.net/detectar-el-control-inalambrico-de-xbox-en-c-net-sin-utilizar-xna/).